# OAuth::getAccessToken() gives me 401

Tags: php, cakephp, twitter, oauth

I am trying to get an access key from Twitter, but get a **401** at `getAccessToken()`.
`OAuth::getRequestToken()` works fine.

Any idea why?

```
App::import('Core', 'CakeSession');

class TwitterSource extends DataSource {

    public $key;
    public $secret;
    private $requestTokenUrl = 'https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token';
    private $authorizeUrl = 'https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize';
    private $accessTokenUrl = 'https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token';

    public function __construct ($config) {
        $this->key = $config['key'];
        $this->secret = $config['secret'];
        $this->Session = new CakeSession();
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function getAuthorizeUrl ($callback) {
        $o = new OAuth($this->key, $this->secret);
        $t = $o->getRequestToken($this->requestTokenUrl, $callback);
        $this->Session->write('twitter_request_token', $t);
        return $this->authorizeUrl.'?'.http_build_query(array(
            'oauth_token' => $t['oauth_token'],
            'oauth_callback' => $callback,
            'force_login' => false
        ));
    }

    public function getAccessToken () {
        $t = $this->Session->read('twitter_request_token');
        if ($t == null) {
            return false;
        }
        $oauth_verifier = isset($_GET['oauth_verifier']) ? $_GET['oauth_verifier'] : null;
        $o = new OAuth($this->key, $this->secret);
        $o->setToken($t['oauth_token'], $t['oauth_token_secret']);
        return $o->getAccessToken($this->accessTokenUrl, null, $oauth_verifier);
    }

}
```

Comment: What error are you getting from back from Twitter when `getAccessToken()` fails?

Comment: I get exactly what I need as an array, sorry my bad, but thanks for pointing me in the right direction.